# What does "c'tee" mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

I have been seeing the word *c'tee* frequently. Here are some examples:

> Sports minister sets up c’tee to find solution to football crisis
> http://www.vanguardngr.com/2011/08/sports-minister-sets-up-ctee-to-find-solution-to-football-crisis/
>
> Trajtenberg C’tee Presenting Final Recommendations Today
> http://www.israelidiamond.co.il/english/news.aspx?boneid=918&objid=9925
>
> ADIA - National C'tee Meetings
> http://www.adia.org.au/meetings/national
>
> Safety & Equipment Audits - YNSW Special Regs C'tee Reports
> http://www.rpayc.com.au/sailing/safety-equipment-audits/page-7
>
> Ramelton Fever Hospital C'tee meeting 1905
> http://www.askaboutireland.ie/reading-room/history-heritage/heritage-towns/the-heritage-towns-of-don/ramelton/ramelton-fever-hospital-c-1/

From the context the word seems to mean either a [political] investigation or a [government] minister. I cannot find any English-English or English-Hebrew dictionary definitions, though. Using Google Translate I cannot find the word in French, German, nor any other obvious European language. What is it, exactly?

Comment: General reference.

Comment: Hah! I had my c++ hat on when I read this, and for a second I thought it would mean "constructee", as c'tor is usually "constructor" ;)

Comment: @Mitch: this question looks like it would be “general reference”, until you try a few of the usual places and find that they don’t list it.  So +1’ing it and the answer, and hoping this question gets high in the google rankings!

Comment: @PLL: Google *[c'tee abbreviation](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c'tee+abbreviation)* and ELU is #1!  It's gen ref now, but only because of this question!

Comment: [C'tee meaning](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c'tee+meaning) brings it to the top too.  Ahhh, the power!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's an abbreviation of *committee*.

Comment: I think it's generally a headline abbreviation as well, and not one that most people would use in other contexts.

Comment: Is this specific to the UK, or have I just never run into it before?

Comment: @onomatomaniak: I've never heard of this abbreviation in the UK. I think Kith might be right it.

Comment: None of the OP’s examples is from a UK source.

Comment: I've usually seen "c'ttee" which is at least semi-guessable.